# Find max difference between two adjacent numbers in an unordered array

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm solves the following in `O(n)` time:

1. Given an *unordered* array of `n` integers (e.g. `{3, 5, 1}`).
2. "Adjacent" means 2 numbers are picked from the *ordered* array `{1, 3, 5}`, and they are adjacent.

**Find the max difference between any pair of numbers that would be adjacent if the array were sorted**.  It's not required to identify which elements were chosen, where they are, or actually sort the array.

I could only find one way that needs huge memory for a huge bitmap.  Mark all numbers in the input in it, then scan the bitmap for the biggest run of zeros.  (This is a [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) with duplicate elimination, thus only requiring a one-bit saturating counter for every possible input number.)

This bitmap solution is more properly `O(n+m)`, where `m` is the size of the needed bitmap = largest input - smallest input.  A small input array containing INT_MAX and INT_MIN is the worst case for this approach.

If necessary or helpful, assume the integers are all [machine word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) `int`s, rather than arbitrary integers.

Comment: `I know there must be an O(n) algorithm to solve this` what makes you sure? If you were looking for "min difference", that would have been element distinctness problem optimization variant, which cannot be solved in O(n) using comparisons based algorithms.

Comment: Could you explain your solution? Because the obvious algorithm with a bitmap is still not quite O(n) but O(n+m) where m is the difference between the largest and the smallest integer in the array, Furthermore it assumes the array contains integers, you did not state that.

Comment: @Henry You are right, it's O(n + m).

Comment: @amit I met this problem in an exam today, my friends and I could not find an right answer.Maybe the problem itself is not right, I have edited the question.

Comment: If all the numbers are known to be integers, you may perform radix sort (O(n)), then scan the array linearly (O(n)).

Comment: @TagirValeev This will give you `O(nlogU)`, where `U` is the range of the elements. In case the range is bigger than the number of elements, you get `logn<logU`. This helps out only in case of many duplicates, in terms of asymptotic complexity

Comment: @amit, with such reasoning every comparison operation has `O(log U)` worst case as it should compare at most `log U` distinct bits. The same for math operations like subtraction (`log U` bits should be processed). Thus the problem cannot be solved even for sorted array in `O(n)`.

Comment: It works wiith an additional constraint that the integers in the array are bounded. Can we assume that?

Comment: Maybe I'm just too sleepy, but I don't understand the question at all.  What are you trying to find?  The max distance in the unsorted array between any adjacent pair in the sorted array?  You said "difference", which to me means subtraction.

Comment: @Henry I think we could assume that if there is no clear solution for the origin question.

Comment: @PeterCordes If the given array is {3, 5, 1}, then the answer should be 2, because in the sorted array{1,3,5}, the max difference between two adjacent numbers  is 2

Comment: @JY___: I think it confused me a lot to only state the problem in the title, and only define the terms (like adjacent) in the body.  I also wasn't 100% sure that the ordered array wasn't a separate input to the algorithm.  Hopefully my edit is an improvment.

Answer (score 1):

Under the further assumption that the size of the integers in the array is bounded, one could do for instance:

1. radix sort of the array -> O(n)
2. find the max difference -> O(n)

or

1. find the min and max integer in the array -> O(n)
2. allocate a bit vector of size max - min + 1 -> O(1) since the size is bounded
3. set all the bits corresponding to a number in the array -> O(n)
4. find the max distance in the bit vector -> O(1) since the size is bounded

Comment: I didn't read this answer before updating the question.  I guess you can say the bitmap is O(1) size, rather than calling it `m`, if you're only talking about the limit as `n` approaches infinity.  For a small array of machine-word integers including INT_MIN and INT_MAX, there's a huge difference between RadixSort and CountingSort.  For 64bit integers, the bitmap would potentially require 2 million 1TB hard drives, so it makes the difference between feasibly implementable or not.  (Yes, I know ~100k storage servers on a network is just a constant factor of overhead. :P)